# Get last <li> element from a string

Tags: php, html

I have a string variable that contains a lot of HTML markup and I want to get the last `<li>` element from it.
Im using something like:

```
$markup = "<body><div><li id='first'>One</li><li id='second'>Two</li><li id='third'>Three</li></div></body>";

preg_match('#<li(.*?)>(.*)</li>#ims', $markup, $matches);
$lis = "<li ".$matches[1].">".$matches[2]."</li>";
$total = explode("</li>",$lis);
$num = count($total)-2;
echo $total[$num]."</li>";
```

This works and I get the last `<li>` element printed. But I cant understand why I have to subtract the last 2 indexes of the array `$total`. Normally I would only subtract the last index since counting starts on index 0. What im i missing?

Is there a better way of getting the last `<li>` element from the string?

Comment: isnt $lis value waht you want ? it seems to me that you get the same result

Comment: tried that. But $lis contains all the <li> elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML is not regular, and so can't be parsed with a regular expression. Use a [proper HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

@OP, your requirement looks simple, so no need for parsers or regex.

```
$markup = "<body><div><li id='first'>One</li><li id='second'>Two</li><li id='third'>Three</li></div></body>";
$s = explode("</li>",$markup,-1);
$t = explode(">",end($s));
print end($t);
```

output

```
$ php test.php
Three
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already know how to use jQuery, you could also take a look at [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). It's a PHP library that allows you to easily access dom elements, just like in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP.net documentation:

```
If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.
```

$matches[0] is the complete match (not just the captured bits)

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the second index because you have 2 capturing groupds:

```
$matches[0]; // Contains your original string
$matches[1]; // Contains the argument for the LI start-tag (.*?)
$matches[2]; // Contains the string contained by the LI tags (.*)
```

'parsing' (x)html strings is with regular expressions is hard and can be full of unexpected problems. parsing more than simple tagged strings is not possible because (x)html is not a regular language.

you could improve your regex by using (not tested):

```
 /#<li([^>]*)>(.+?)</li>#ims/
```

Comment: that explains the weird result. Didnt quite understand the php  documentation for it.But ill use the html parser since this is something ill need to use a few times. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

strrpos — Find position of last occurrence of a char in a string